# How to add CMake config to build tree

Tags: cmake

I have a shared library in my project with a cmake config file. How can I make it available in the build tree such that I don't have to install it before using `find_package`?

Comment: "I have a shared library in my project with a cmake config file." - Not clear what do you actually have. Do you have the `.lib`/`.so`/`.a` file, or your project just issues `add_library` call for non-IMPORTED library? What CMake config file do you have? Is this file **intended** to be installed? If yes, then you cannot use this file unless the library's project is installed.

Comment: As said a shared library. What is this lib extension? .a is static. so on linux but actually i am on a mac, therefore a .dylib. The library is the core of my app. Plugins need  to use its interface. Sure it is intended to be installed. Users may waxnt to write their own plugins, but the app comes with several plugins as well. Since this looks like a relative common use case to me i tend to not believe that it is impossible.

Comment: If you are about using the same config file, then no, you cannot use it, as it contains either paths (absolute or relative) which are **specific to the install tree**, and which could be wrong for the build tree. If you are about the using the library, then yes, you could write a config/module file for it and use via `find_package`. If you are a developer of that library, then you could look into [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html) command for create a config file which exposes the build tree of the project.

Comment: I think `export(PACKAGE…` is what I want. I set `CMAKE_EXPORT_PACKAGE_REGISTRY`. But get errors on `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@PROJECT_NAME@-targets.cmake")` in the config file

Comment: "get errors on ..." is not a description of a problem with which we can help you. You need to show the exact error message, the code, ... well, with over 15k reputation you should be perfectly aware about the content of a good question post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, "File not found". Its hard for me to be precise, because I dont really understand how things work together here. I am confused.. :D All tutorials I saw include via CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR. Actually I dont know when and how this will be resolved. Let alone if this makes sense for the find_package caller, whose directory probably does not have a targets file.

Comment: The line `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@PROJECT_NAME@-targets.cmake")` implies that the config file is located in the **same directory** as `@PROJECT_NAME@-targets.cmake` file generated by `export(TARGETS)` command. Check that this is your case.

Comment: Just realized that CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE is _not_ necesarily a CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism I was looking for is [`export(PACKAGE <PackageName>)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html#exporting-packages). Note that since 3.15 the command does nothing by default because populating the user package registry has effects outside the source and build trees. You have to set the CMAKE_EXPORT_PACKAGE_REGISTRY variable to add build directories to the CMake user package registry.

I was able to get things working like this:

```
install(
    TARGETS ${TARGET_LIB}
    EXPORT TARGET_LIB_EXPORTS  # Define exports
    FILE "${PROJECT_NAME}-targets.cmake"
    …
)

# Create targets file in build tree
export(
    EXPORT TARGET_LIB_EXPORTS
    FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-targets.cmake"
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
)

# Create config file in build tree
configure_package_config_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}-config.cmake.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}
)

# Create version config file in build tree
write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${PROJECT_NAME}-config-version.cmake"
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)

# Export the package to make find_package work in build
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_PACKAGE_REGISTRY true)
export(PACKAGE ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

A basic config file would look like this:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@PROJECT_NAME@-targets.cmake")
```